# swift declare variable of subtype with reference of super type

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to use polymorphism in swift but I'm doing something wrong; I have the following scenario:

```
class Character : NSNode {
 let characterName = "name"
}

class World : NSNode {
 let character : NSNode = Character()
 // getting error here, NSNode does not have a property "characterName"
 character.characterName = "new name" 
}
```

what's the correct way of declaring a variable of type Character() but has reference type NSNode()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(character as Character).characterName = "new name"
```

This feature of Swift is not unusual. You have typed `character` as NSNode so that is all the compiler knows about it. To tell the compiler what sort of object it really is (e.g. what subclass of NSNode), you cast down.

There is nothing wrong with your declaration, provided you are willing to cast down every time you want to access a Character feature. But did you have some reason for not just typing `character` as a Character to begin with? After all, Swift knows perfectly that this means it is also an NSNode. It seems to me that you may have your notion of polymorphism somewhat topsy-turvy.

Comment: doesn't this lose the point of polymorphism slightly though? I'm used to Java where you can say "Fruit a = new Apple()" and the compiler can see all the properties of both super and sub class

Comment: I can't answer that; I've never used a language with such a peculiar idea of what polymorphism means. :) In Ruby there is "duck typing", meaning that any message can be sent to anything and you take your chances; but Swift's typing is just the opposite - it is super-strict and determinate.

Comment: maybe learning Java first wasn't a good idea :/ - which is a good thing, strongly typed languages are cleaner in my opinion